# Migration ASP.NET application from iis 6 to iis 8 causing "Thread Abort exception" in anchor tag

Tags: asp.net, iis, migration, iis-8

I'm migrating a ASP.NET application (3.0) from an old server (2003) to a new 2012 R2 server with iis 8. I copy the whole application and create a website. The first page loads fine but upon clicking any of the anchor tags which redirect the app to some other page, I get a "Thread was being aborted" error.

Any idea what could be causing this? 
I seems to work fine on the old server, so I guess I'm missing out some iis setting.

Answer (score 0):

PS: the issue has been solved. 
The correct authentication mode was not enabled in IIS, and the code required the current user object, which was not available due to the same.

Hence, the issue.

Changing the `auth-type` from `Anonymous` to `Windows` solved the issue.